# How scope related with timesheet in versionOne?

Tags: versionone, downcast

I am completely new in VersionApi implementaion. Before starting I would like to gather a initial information like below:

1. How can we fetch Scope/Project using VersionOne API?
2. How scope and Timesheet mapped with each other, where I can get that mapping diagram?

I went throught the VersionOne API document but did not get any direct source?

Comment: Show your effort first.

Comment: Flagged for off topic - external resources

Comment: Hello, I went through https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Getting_Started/Platform_Concepts/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData this link. but did not find much

Comment: That's sad, but SO is for programming questions, not got gathering initial information

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got something which gives complete idea about mapping between different entitie:
http://YourVersionOne/meta.v1?xsl=api.xsl.